# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a (1 - a)^{n-1} b^{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following expression which I have reduced to the following:

$$X = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a (1 - a)^{n-1} b^{2^{n-1}}$$
$$X = a \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - a)^{n-1} b^{2^{n-1}}$$
$$X = a [a^0 b^{2^{0}} + a^{1} b^{2^{1}} + a^2 b^{2^{2}} + ...]$$
$$X = a [b + a b^{2^{1}} + a^2 b^{2^{2}} + ...]$$
$$X = a b [1 + a b^{2^{1} - 1} + a^2 b^{2^{2} - 1} + ...]$$

where $|a|<1,|b|<1$. Then,is there an expression for the term in brackets?:

$$1 + a b^{2^{1} - 1} + a^2 b^{2^{2} - 1} + ...$$

Comment: I would say $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a^i b^{2^i-1}$?